# Magento Random Order Status goes back to Processing after marked as Process Printed / Shipped

Tags: magento2.2.6, m2epro

I have a very strange problem with my Magento 2.2.6.

I am using M2E Pro to import orders automatically from Amazon. All the orders will be listed in Orders with Pending Status.

Then I would run a mass action to create invoice with status Paid.

Then I would put status to Process Printed(Custom Status with Processing State).

Next the issue happens. After some time (some 4 hours, some after 1 day, mostly random time) the status automatically changed to Processing. This not logged in comment history, not in the logs of M2E pro, not in the logs of any cron jobs(I have checked the updated time matching with the logs).

[image]

Comment History

[image]

And in the DB both the state and status is processing. As it's not added to the comment history makes this unable to trace.

Anybody have any idea why this is happening and how to trace this. I have looked in to all the solutions from the issue with automatic status change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got a clue from M2E that the order status changed from their extension and writing to them has given me the below reply. That didn't solve the problem but at least have a clue what is going on.

> This Update Date in order is the date which Amazon returned for the particular order. M2E just displays this date.
>   It looks like there was nothing changed in order ( the status remains Unshipped), however, Amazon returned it as a changed order. Once order updated is received M2E pro applies the order mapping settings from Amazon account and set status.
>
> Here is the problem, that M2E Pro does not expect that unchanged order is returned as changed. We have never seen this before. So either there's some temporary Amazon glitch or there were some changes in Amazon behavior.
>
> I will keep monitoring this issue and consult our devs on this. I will get back yo you ones I have more details